# TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, -1, 3]. Consider casting elements to a supported type

Tags: list, tensorflow, seq2seq

I get an error for datatype mismatch in Tensorflow.

I tried to do:

```
prediction = tf.convert_to_tensor(prediction)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
```

before passing it to loss function

```py
def train():
    print("Training")

    # tf Graph input
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, config.input_window_size - 1, config.input_size], name="input_sequence")
    y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, config.output_window_size, config.input_size], name="raw_labels")
    dec_in = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, config.output_window_size, config.input_size], name="decoder_input")

    labels = tf.transpose(y, [1, 0, 2])
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, config.input_size])
    labels = tf.split(labels, config.output_window_size, axis=0, name='labels')

    tf.set_random_seed(112858)


    # Define model
    prediction = models.seq2seq(x, dec_in, config, True)

    sess = tf.Session()

    loss = eval('loss_functions.lie_loss(prediction, labels, config)')

    # Add a summary for the loss
    train_loss = tf.summary.scalar('train loss', loss)
    valid_loss = tf.summary.scalar('valid loss', loss)
```

Loss function

```py
def lie_loss(prediction, y, config):
    # Compute the joint discrepancy following forward kinematics of lie parameters

    prediction = tf.concat(prediction, axis=0)
    y = tf.concat(y, axis=0)

    joint_pred = forward_kinematics(prediction, config)
    joint_label = forward_kinematics(y, config)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(joint_pred, joint_label)))

    return loss
```

I get error 
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: [None, -1, 3]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

On making the change of prediction and y to tensor, I get following error in Forward_kinematics:

```
joint_pred = forward_kinematics(prediction, config)
Prediction/src/loss_functions.py", line 101, in forward_kinematics
    for i in range(omega[0].shape[0]):

TypeError: __index__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

Function for forward_kinematics is as follows:

```py
def forward_kinematics(lie_parameters, config):
    print(lie_parameters)
    nframes = lie_parameters.get_shape().as_list()[0]
    print("nframs")
    print(nframes)
    # nframes = lie_parameters.shape[0]
    lie_parameters = tf.reshape(lie_parameters, [nframes, -1, 3])

    R = []
    idx = config.idx
    chain_idx = config.chain_idx
    # config bone params are retrieved from read_data.py

    bone_params = config.bone_params
    for h in range(nframes):
        omega = []
        A = []
        chain = []
        for i in range(len(idx) - 1):
            chain.append(tf.concat([lie_parameters[h, idx[i]:idx[i + 1]], tf.zeros([1, 3])], axis=0))

        omega.append(tf.concat(chain, axis=0))

        ##### I have to check this omega
        print("Omega")
        print(type(omega))
        print(omega)
        print(omega[0])
        print(omega[0].shape)
        print(omega[0].shape[0])

        for i in range(omega[0].shape[0]):
            A.append([rotmat(omega[0][i])])
        R.append(tf.concat(A, axis=0))

    R = tf.stack(R)
    joints = []
    for h in range(nframes):
        jointlist = []
        for i in range(len(chain_idx)):
            for j in range(chain_idx[i].shape[0]):
                if j == 0:
                    if i < 3:
                        jointlist.append(tf.zeros([3, 1]))
                    else:
                        jointlist.append(joint_xyz[14])
                else:
                    k = j - 1
                    A = R[h, chain_idx[i][k]]
                    while k > 0:
                        k = k - 1
                        A = tf.matmul(R[h, chain_idx[i][k]], A)
                    jointlist.append(
                        tf.matmul(A, tf.reshape(bone_params[chain_idx[i][j]], [3, 1])) + joint_xyz[chain_idx[i][j - 1]])
                joint_xyz = tf.stack(jointlist)
        joints.append(tf.squeeze(joint_xyz))
    joints = tf.stack(joints)
    return joints
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar kind of issue.I first transposed and then reshaped.It might helps you.My task was to unroll the tensor.I have to compute content cost in neural style transfer.
[image]

```
 a_C_unrolled = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(a_C,perm=[0,3,1,2]),shape=[m,n_H*n_W,n_C])
    a_G_unrolled =tf.reshape( tf.transpose(a_G,perm=[0,3,1,2]),shape=[m,n_H*n_W,n_C])
```

Additional Hints for "Unrolling"

```
To unroll the tensor, we want the shape to change from (m,nH,nW,nC)(m,nH,nW,nC) to (m,nH×nW,nC)(m,nH×nW,nC).

tf.reshape(tensor, shape) takes a list of integers that represent the desired output shape.

For the shape parameter, a -1 tells the function to choose the correct dimension size so that the output tensor still contains all the values of the original tensor.

So tf.reshape(a_C, shape=[m, n_H * n_W, n_C]) gives the same result as tf.reshape(a_C, shape=[m, -1, n_C]).

If you prefer to re-order the dimensions, you can use tf.transpose(tensor, perm), where perm is a list of integers containing the original index of the dimensions.

For example, tf.transpose(a_C, perm=[0,3,1,2]) changes the dimensions from (m,nH,nW,nC)(m,nH,nW,nC) to (m,nC,nH,nW)(m,nC,nH,nW).

There is more than one way to unroll the tensors.
Notice that it's not necessary to use tf.transpose to 'unroll' the tensors in this case but this is a useful function to practice and understand for other situations that you'll encounter.
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood where the problem is

when you are putting these dimensions into a list object it converts int32 to Dimension(x) you can try to cast it with tensorflow but it did not work for me and as you again need to convert it to a Tensor , so you can use the below code to cast it without tensorflow

```
a_C_unrolled =  tf.reshape(a_C, shape=tf.constant([int(m), int(n_H * n_W), int(n_C)]))
a_G_unrolled =  tf.reshape(a_G, shape=tf.constant([int(m), int(n_H * n_W), int(n_C)]))
```

Note :-

You can try to use np.cast

```
a_C_unrolled= tf.reshape(a_C,shape=list(map(int,[n_C,n_H*n_W])))
```